# Create user in production or in local host for django

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

I don't know if this is a newbie question. But basically, I have website hosted on Pythonanywhere. When I want to make changes, the normal workflow is to make changes locally -> commit and push changes to github -> pull changes to pythonanywhere(PA) console and migrate.

At the moment, I create accounts for my users manually and an email is then automatically sent to them with a link to set their own password. I do this like this.

```
            uid = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))
            token =  default_token_generator.make_token(user)
            reset_view = reverse('password_reset_confirm', args=[uid, token])
            url = request.build_absolute_uri( reset_view )

            set_password_form  = PasswordResetForm({'email':email})
            assert set_password_form.is_valid()
            set_password_form.save(
                request=request,
                from_email="email",
                subject_template_name='accounts/welcome_email_subject.txt',
                email_template_name="accounts/welcome_email_template.html",
                html_email_template_name="accounts/welcome_email_template.html",
                extra_email_context = {'url':url , 'username':username,"name":name}
            )
```

I recently just realized that the domain of the generated password reset link depends on where I created the user account from. So if i created the user on localhost, the domain will be  `127.0. 0.0` but if I created the account in Pythonanywhere, the domain will be `mywebsite.com`. Say if I decided to create an account on local server. the domain will be localhost so if I closed my computer before the user clicked on the link, they won't be able to set their password as the server will be down. That rules out the idea that i should be creating the user locally.

But if I decided to create the user on PA, then wouldn't that mean in addition to the normal workflow, I also will have to be pushing changes from production server to github then pulling them to local server each time I do so? Is there something I'm missing out on or is this just the reality?

Comment: I think you're confusing few things here: users don't have access to your localhost, so the link would not work as you expect to work -- "development" and "production" environments are not only different "places" but have different purposes and should be used differently.  Another thing is using the version control system (git) -- if you make changes in the production environment, you should commit and push them, like you do when you make changes locally.  But -- you should rather separate your app's behaviour in prod and dev via the setup, not via overriding previous commits all the time.

Comment: I understood what you said up until the last sentence "you should rather separate your app's behaviour in prod and dev via the setup, not via overriding previous commits all the time." What do you mean that?

Comment: Normally you'll have differences in the code that you want in your `settings,py` when running on your local machine, as compared to the code you need there when you're running in your production environment.  This tutorial is a good introduction as to how to separate them: https://thinkster.io/tutorials/configuring-django-settings-for-production